# AngularJS 1.3: table view displayed not correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

I’m working on Angular project where I have a table populated of elements from the server an API. The table should have an alternate color of the rows as from template. However, in my case is gray completely and I need help to fix that. 
This table is the consequence of 2 list merged in once and I think this cause the error.

In the HTML I tried to put the **ng-repeat** on the row instead of the body how is looking right now, but that cause my rows were going app or down when the button was clicked for activate it. The rows simply were not staying fixed in the position where the action was happening. So, I decided to put the **ng-repeat** in the **tbody** instead.

I’m searching a better solution to maintain the table as original template and to have still the same functionality. I think I should do something in the ctrl but still I don’t know which modification I should do.

I'm sharing code of the table, controller and a screenshot of the table:

Table:

```
<div ng-show="analyticsEmailSettings.subscribed">
                <!--|| Table Start For Subcribed WebSites ||-->
                <table ng-table="tableParams" template-pagination="/js/directives/termstable/pagination.html" class="table full-width no-border" id="tableEnginesMyaccount">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="width-635">
                                {{ 'engine_step1_name' | translate }}
                            </th>
                            <th class="width-30">
                                {{ 'user_settings_emailStatistics_weekly' | translate }}
                            </th>
                            <th class="width-30">
                                {{ 'user_settings_emailStatistics_monthly' | translate }}
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody ng-repeat="websites in engines | orderBy:'name'">

                        <!--!loading && $data.length-->
                        <tr class="tr-active" ng-if="websites.type == 'WeeklyAnalytics' || websites.type == 'MonthlyAnalytics'">
                            <td colspan="" class="list__item--action-menu" ng-mouseover="isActive=true" ng-mouseleave="isActive=false">
                                {{websites.name}}
                                <span class="float-right">
                                    <button class="button button--primary button--delete" ng-click="removeEngineFromSubscriptionServer(websites)"> <!-- enableDisable(websites) -->
                                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="td-with-button center valign-top">
                                <span class="cursor-pointer" ng-click="updateEngineToSubscription(websites,'WeeklyAnalytics')">
                                    <i class="icon--big fa" ng-class="{'fa-check-circle-o' : websites.type == 'WeeklyAnalytics', 'fa-circle-o' : websites.type != 'WeeklyAnalytics'}"></i>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="td-with-button center valign-top">
                                <span class="cursor-pointer" ng-click="updateEngineToSubscription(websites,'MonthlyAnalytics')">
                                    <i class="icon--big fa" ng-class="{'fa-check-circle-o' : websites.type == 'MonthlyAnalytics', 'fa-circle-o' :  websites.type != 'MonthlyAnalytics'}"></i>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="tr-no-active" ng-if="websites.type != 'WeeklyAnalytics' && websites.type != 'MonthlyAnalytics'">
                            <td colspan="" class="txt-no-active">
                                {{websites.name}}

                            </td>

                            <td class="td-with-button center valign-top" colspan="2">

                                <button class="button button--primary button--enable" ng-click="addEngineToSubscription(websites)"> <!-- enableDisable(websites) -->
                                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                    <!--enable-->
                                </button>
                            </td>

                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                    <!-- No Content -->
                    <tbody ng-show="engines.length == 0">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4" class="center">
                                <h3>
                                    {{ 'statistic_table_footer_no_data' | translate }}
                                </h3>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
                <!--|| Table End ||-->
            </div>
```

Controller:

```
searchApp.controller('UserSettingsCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', 'aiStorage', 'userConfig', 'UserSettingsService', 'WebsiteSource', 'AnalyticsEmailService', 'toaster', '$translate', '$timeout',
function ($scope, $q, store, userConfig, UserSettingsService, WebsiteSource, AnalyticsEmailService, toaster, $translate, $timeout) {

$scope.groupBy = function (key) {
  return $scope.subscriptionEngines.filter(function (obj) {
    return obj.type == key;
  })
}
$scope.init = function () {
  $scope.availableLanguages = {
    da: 'Dansk',
    en: 'English',
    sv: 'Svensk'
  };
  $scope.userInfo = store.get('user');
  $scope.loadingAction = false;
  $scope.selectFlag = false;
  $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer = [];
  $scope.subscriptionEngines = [];
  $scope.analyticsEmailSettings = {};
  $scope.engines = angular.copy(WebsiteSource.sites);
  AnalyticsEmailService.getUserSubscription().then(
    function success(response) {
      $scope.loadingAction = false;
      $scope.subscription = response;
      console.log('response.data', response.data)
      $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer = populateSubscribedEnginesFromServer(response.data);
      $scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscribed = (response.data.length > 0);
    },
    function error() {});
}

function populateSubscribedEnginesFromServer(data) {
  //console.log('data', data)
  var subscriptionEngines = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var subscription = data[i];
    var engine = $scope.engines.filter(function (x) {
      if (x.id === subscription.engine) {
        var index = $scope.engines.indexOf(x);
        //debugger
        //Added type
        $scope.engines[index].type = subscription.type;
      }
      return x.id === subscription.engine;
    })[0];
    console.log('engine', engine);
    if (engine) subscription.name = engine.name;

    subscriptionEngines.push(subscription);


  }
  console.log('subscriptionEngines', subscriptionEngines)
  return subscriptionEngines;
}


$scope.save = function () {
  $scope.loadingAction = true;
  if ($scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscribed) {
    // var putArray = [];
    //debugger;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.subscriptionEngines.length; i++) {
      var obj = {
        "type": $scope.subscriptionEngines[i].type,
        "engine": $scope.subscriptionEngines[i].id || $scope.subscriptionEngines[i].engine,
        "title": $scope.subscriptionEngines[i].name,
        "name": $scope.subscriptionEngines[i].name
      };
      $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer.push(obj);
    }
    //debug
    //console.log('putArray', putArray)
    AnalyticsEmailService.updatesubscriptions($scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer, function success(response) {

    }, function error() {});
    $timeout(function () {
      AnalyticsEmailService.getUserSubscription().then(
        function success(response) {

          $scope.loadingAction = false;
          $scope.subscription = response;
          //console.log('response.data', populateSubscribedEnginesFromServer(response.data))
          // $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer = populateSubscribedEnginesFromServer(response.data);
          $scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscribed = (response.data.length > 0);
          //debugger
        },
        function error() {});
    }, 1000)

  } else {
    AnalyticsEmailService.unsubscribe($scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscription, function success(response) {}, function error() {});
  }
  UserSettingsService.save({
    userId: $scope.userInfo.id
  }, $scope.userInfo, function () {

    $scope.loadingAction = false;
    userConfig.setCurrentUserConfig($scope.userInfo);
    userConfig.setUserLocale();
    store.set('user', $scope.userInfo);
    toaster.pop({
      type: 'success',
      body: $translate.instant('notifications_user_settings_changed_success')
    });
  }, function () {});
  $scope.subscriptionEngines = [];
};

//removeSelectedEngines
$scope.getUnselectedEngines = function () {
  if (!$scope.engines)
    return [];

  var unselectedEngines = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.engines.length; i++) {

    if ($scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer.filter(function (x) {
        return x.engine === $scope.engines[i].id;
      }).length == 0)
      unselectedEngines.push($scope.engines[i]);

  }

  //All engines

  return unselectedEngines;

}

$scope.addEngineToSubscription = function (engine) {

  $scope.subscriptionEngines = [];

  var index = $scope.engines.indexOf(engine);
  //debugger
  $scope.engines[index].type = "WeeklyAnalytics";
  engine.type = "WeeklyAnalytics";
  $scope.subscriptionEngines.push(engine);
  $scope.save();



}
$scope.updateEngineToSubscription = function (engine, type) {
  $scope.subscriptionEngines = [];
  var index = $scope.engines.indexOf(engine);
  //debugger
  $scope.engines[index].type = type;
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer[i].engine == engine.id) {
      //Added Type
      $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer[i].type = type;
      break;
    }
  }

  $scope.save();



}

$scope.removeEngineFromSubscriptionServer = function (engine) {
  $scope.subscriptionEngines = [];
  var index = $scope.engines.indexOf(engine);
  //debugger
  $scope.engines[index].type = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer[i].engine == engine.id) {
      $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    }
  }

  $scope.save();

}}]);
```

ScreenShot:

[screenshot of the table - notice it is not color alternate of the rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VELY1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are looking for the alternate row color then you can do by *$even* and *$odd* properties of [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

```
 <tr ng-repeat-start="websites in engines | orderBy:'name' track by $index" ng-class="{'odd-row': $odd, 'even-row': $even}"">
```

whereas I am using `even-row` and `odd-row` are the class name

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. However after a discussion with my CTO. He said I will be able to modify the controller where 2 functions care about the UI and what is going to the server. He said I should have one list and do operation on it. My items coming no active from the server I activate it after clicking the button the are saved to the server. I need to figure out how to make this one list from what i have and with a loop and filter, that was the input I received.

Comment: create other issue and we can help

Comment: Hi, I used your idea for something else. So was useful :)
By the way, I resolved this issue rebuilding the controller and merging some methods into one. I merged, in the end, the 2 list in the controller.